# What's the best way to add a trailing slash to a pathlib directory?

Tags: python, pathlib

I have a directory I'd like to print out with a trailing slash: `my_path = pathlib.Path('abc/def')`

Is there a nicer way of doing this than `os.path.join(str(my_path), '')`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, you didn't miss anything. By design, `pathlib` strips trailing slashes, and provides no way to display paths with trailing slashes. This has annoyed several people, as mentioned in the bug tracker: [pathlib strips trailing slash](https://bugs.python.org/issue21039).

A compact way to add slashes in Python 3.6 is to use an f-string, eg `f'{some_path}/'` or `f'{some_path}{os.sep}'` if you want to be OS-agnostic.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

some_path = '/etc'
p = Path(some_path)
print(f'{p}/')
print(f'{p}{os.sep}')
```

**output**

```
/etc/
/etc/
```

Another option is to add a dummy component and slice it off the resulting string:

```
print(str(p/'@')[:-1])
```

Comment: The two ways may not equivalent: `os.sep` always represents the separator of the system’s path flavour, while a path can have a different separator.

Comment: @EugeneYarmash Indeed. But the OP is simply adding a slash for display purposes: "I have a directory I'd like to print out with a trailing slash". So we don't really need to worry about it for this particular case.  And if you're actually building paths with `pathlib`, then you should let `pathlib` handle the details... unless you're in the situation mentioned in that bug tracker link and you need to supply a pathname with a trailing slash to some program that needs it, and in which case you're probably on a Posix system anyway.

Comment: The dummy component is probably preferable - there are paths without trailing slashes where `p/` doesn't add `os.sep`, e.g. `Path(/)` etc (`/` can be a valid parent for example, e.g. `Path(/rootfile.txt)`, so using `os.sep` to connect `path.parent` and `path.name` in general would be wrong!)

Comment: @GPhys Sure, but this question (& my answer) is about manipulating path *strings* to make a human-friendly representation for printing (but I guess it's also useful for saving path strings to CSV, JSON, etc). The main motivation for the `pathlib` module is to treat paths as objects and to manipulate them using the module functions / methods, so as to avoid the problems that can arise with the old `os.path` string-oriented approach.

Comment: The question is explicitly about pathlib directories; `Path("/")` is a pathlib directory (`is_dir()` is `True`)

Answer (score 4):

To add a trailing slash of the path's flavour using just `pathlib` you could do:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> my_path = Path("abc/def")
>>> str(my_path / "_")[:-1]  # add a dummy "_" component, then strip it
'abc/def/'
```

Looking into the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/pathlib.py), there's also a `Path._flavour.sep` attribute:

```
>>> str(my_path) + my_path._flavour.sep
'abc/def/'
```

But it doesn't seem to have any documented accessor yet.

Comment: Thanks for that info about `_flavour.sep`, although I'm wary about using undocumented features: they can disappear without notice. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
os.path.normpath(str(my_path)) + os.sep
```

I would say it is down to preference rather than being "nicer"

Comment: to clarify, i'm hoping there's something i missed in the `Path` class itself... seems a cop-out to import `os.path` to do the job.

Comment: and `os.path.normpath(my_path)` raises "AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'startswith'" --> needs to be `os.path.normpath(str(my_path))`

Comment: @Tom, no you didn't miss anything.  By design, `pathlib` strips trailing slashes, and provides no way to display paths with trailing slashes. This has annoyed several people, see [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue21039). A compact way to add slashes in Python 3.6 is to use an f-string, eg `f'{some_path}/'` or `f'{some_path}{os.sep}'` if you want to be OS-agnostic.

Comment: I think that deserves to be an answer as it's the neatest option by far (though i'm stuck on 3.4 for a while :( )

Comment: @Tom Oh, ok. I don't normally do f-string answers, since they can be frustrating for people using older versions. Beware: f-strings are _highly_ addictive, and _much_ faster than the other formatting options. :)

Comment: 3.6 is nearly a year old, people should be shown the reasons to upgrade :)