# What is the most effective ways to 'normalize' directory paths in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, directory, path, absolute-path

Long-time veteran of C# and Swift, but new to Python so forgive me if this is a basic question.

I'm trying to solve a seemingly simple problem. We have a Python3 function that takes a list of directories represented as a string array.  We're using those values in some outputted JSON and in that JSON, it has to have a guaranteed format.

What we're trying to address is the following case (Note: This will either be on macOS or Linux):

```
File 1: /Users/Joe/Some/Path/To/Folder/
File 2: /Users/Joe/Some/Path/To/Folder   <-- Note the missing trailing slash
File 3: ~/Some/Path/To/Folder/           <-- Note the 'home' tilde
```

All three of the above should output a format matching File 1 above...

```
/Users/Joe/Some/Path/To/Folder/
```

Well I can do this with regex and/or string manipulation, I’m hoping there’s something in a standard library‘s that I can use, especially to get platform-independence where on some systems things are forward-slashes and others they are back-slashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you expect of a ``FileInfo``-like object? Are you aware of the standard library ``pathlib`` and ``pathlib.Path``?

Comment: I'm not interested in the FileInfo itself. I'm more interested in getting normalized string representations and I was trying to avoid manually checking for trailing slash characters, etc.  That object in other languages encapsulates all that logic for me so I don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I'm mainly asking because I'm wondering whether you expect the program to detect whether the path points to a directory, or should just unconditionally append ``/``.

Comment: Definitely the former.  That's the entire point!  BUT... I just found `os.path.abspath` which seems to take all three above and always outputs #2, so if I use that, I can just append a slash!

Answer (score 2):

The canonical tools for handling paths are the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and low-level [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) standard libraries. Both handle paths in a platform independent way, though it is customary to use the UNIX convention of `/` path separator. `pathlib` additionally supports platform specific behaviour by explicitly using `pathlib.PosixPath`/`pathlib.PurePosixPath` or `pathlib.WindowsPath`/`pathlib.PureWindowsPath`; the `Pure...` variants can be used cross-platform.

---

Using `pathlib` allows to explicitly `.expanduser()` and optionally `.resolve()` it given logical or actual file system operations. A `pathlib.Path` [*always* removes trailing separators](https://bugs.python.org/issue21039); if a trailing separator is desired (e.g. to indicate directory or link handling), [it must be added explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572165/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-trailing-slash-to-a-pathlib-directory).

```py
import random
import pathlib

raw_path = random.choice(['/Users/Joe/Some/Path/To/Folder/', '/Users/Joe/Some/Path/To/Folder', '~/Some/Path/To/Folder/'])

path = pathlib.Path(raw_path).expanduser().resolve()  # normalize path
rawdir_path = str(path/'-')[:-1]                      # format with trailing separator
print(rawdir_path)
```